# How to see/monitor the SUBscribers to my zeromq PUBlisher?

Tags: java, c++, monitoring, zeromq, traffic

I am building a application in which I want a number of subscribers to be able to connect to my zeromq publisher. I'm now want to see some information about the subscribers;

- how many subscribers are connected?
- which ip addresses they are coming from?

Does anybody know of a way to do this in zeromq (by using setsockopt for example) or is there a way that I can build this myself? More information on this would be very good.

Answer (score 1):

> which ip addresses they are coming from?

You cannot get the IP of subscribers, this information is abstracted in ZeroMq, but there are options, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14655860/791406).

> how many subscribers are connection?

Using socket [monitor events](http://api.zeromq.org/3-2:zmq-socket-monitor), the publisher *may* keep track of subscriber peers that connect and close their connection, however, this is not full-proof. The recommended approach is using [heartbeats](https://github.com/zeromq/jeromq/issues/61) between peers to keep track of who is alive (and dead). Check the guide for info and examples on this subject.